# Angular2: recursive routes in children

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

In Angular 2, there is a route like this:

```
{ path: 'contents/:id', component: ContentComponent }
```

this works perfect when I /contents/1 is accessed.
Let's say that the ContentComponent has many ContentComponent children, in other words, Content has many Contents.

Is it possible to make this route recursive with children?
Like: /contents/1/contents/20, /contents/1/contents/20/contents/54, /contents/1/contents/20/contents/54/contents/34324

Comment: did you find any solution so far ??

Comment: @SadokMtir no. I changed my app to avoid nested and recursive routes. Now they ar all "plain": /{modelname}/{id}, I avoid the use of /{modelname}/{id}/{anothermodelname}/{otherid}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use children ?

```
{
  path: 'contents/:id',
  component: ContentComponent,
  children: [
     path: 'contents/:id',
     component: AnotherContentComponent,
  ]
}
```

Comment: The problem is this ' again nested child route': I don't know how many levels will be. It must be recursive, but I don't know if his is possible.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler nested routes handled by children in `angular2`. I don't know what you mean saying recursive

Answer (score 0):

The route has a `children:[]` which contains child routes. Yet you have to design your app for this to achieve what you are looking for:

```
{ path: 'contents/:id', component: ContentComponent, children:[
  {path:'child1', component:TheChild1Component, children:[ {nested child route}]},
  {path:'child2', component:TheChild2Component, children:[ { another nested child route}]}
   ...
] }
```

Comment: The problem is this ' again nested child route': I don't know how many levels will be. It must be recursive, but I don't know if his is possible.